# RESTful Web Services for Flex

Tags: web-services, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I am quite new to Flex (virtually got tossed into it...lol). I am trying to display the message that I have created in the web service. I keep getting the return error **"Security error accessing url Destination: DefaultHTTP"**

Here is a copy of my code...I know it may be something simple. I created the Data Service for configuring the HTTP Service and I tested the operation and everything was successful when testing...just having a little trouble showing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
           xmlns:restsrv="services.restsrv.*"
           minWidth="955" minHeight="600" applicationComplete="init ()">

<fx:Declarations>

    <mx:HTTPService id="service" url="http://servername/RestService/Service.svc/XMLService/hi"  method="POST" resultFormat="e4x" />



    <restsrv:Restsrv id="restsrv"
                     fault="Alert.show(event.fault.faultString + '\n' + event.fault.faultDetail)"
                     showBusyCursor="true"/>        
    <s:CallResponder id="RESTfulResult"/>
</fx:Declarations>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        import mx.rpc.http.HTTPService;
        import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
        import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;


        protected function form_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            RESTfulResult.token = restsrv.RESTful();
            /* rESTfulTextInput.text = RESTfulResult.toString(); */
            service.send();                 
        }                   
    ]]>
</fx:Script>


<s:Form id="form" creationComplete="form_creationCompleteHandler(event)">
    <s:FormItem label="RESTful">
        <s:TextInput id="rESTfulTextInput" text="{RESTfulResult.lastResult as String}"/>
    </s:FormItem>
</s:Form>


</s:Application>
```

This is how the code looks when adding the correct syntax you suggested lxx

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="http://my-server-name-dev3/RestService/Service.svc/XMLService/hi" />
</cross-domain-policy>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
           xmlns:restsrv="services.restsrv.*"
           minWidth="955" minHeight="600" applicationComplete="init ()">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not running this code also from http://servername you have same origin policy problem. You can solve it adding the client host to crossdomain.xml in server.

For localhost for example you have to add

```
<allow-access-from domain="localhost"/>
```

Comment: I checked and we have the crossdomain.xml on that dedicated server. I have tried to enter this in my code but getting an error that is is malformed.

Comment: You must have that line in the crossdomain.xml, not in your client code.

Comment: We tried adding this to the crossdomain.xml, but I was unsuccessful at displaying the string. Could there be anything else?

Comment: Watch network traffic with firefox or developer tools. If the last response you get contains crossdomain.xml and then nothing else happens, it's cross domain problem. You can look the content of crossdomain.xml there and check. If the error is something else, watching network traffic or console is also helpful.